# How can I get the most common headers at this moment?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using the Python requests library to scrape, but I am pasting headers in the code:

```
headers_list = [
            {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'},
            {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'},
            {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'},
            {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'},
            {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}]
```

Over time, the headers will no longer be the most common headers.

Is there a way to get the most common headers at this moment?

Comment: Do you need a custom header? Do you have an error?

Comment: @JayeRenzoMontejo I don´t undestand you, ¿where capture the values?

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I do it

Comment: @JRichardsz If I don´t set a header, the websites usually refuse my scraping

Comment: Must be a strange page. What you need is to get the error log.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the browser inspection. With that you could have a complete details of request, not only the headers

You only need to open the web in your favorite browser, inspect it, in network tab choose one of the first request and right click and get what you need from the request

[image]

[image]

### Advice

Sometimes the headers are not the problem in a web scrapping. It could be:

- Web content is loaded with ajax and takes long
- Some security strategy like login, captcha, etc
- White list access at ip layer
- Some advanced and complex javascript protection

### Alternatives

Selenium uses a real browser, so no matter what, the web page should be opened

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/foo/bar/libs/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```